# Angular APP_INITIALIZER to load config file in tests

Tags: angular

I'm using this [gist](https://gist.github.com/fernandohu/122e88c3bcd210bbe41c608c36306db9) to read configuration file during application startup. This works fine but when doing unit tests I get error `Cannot read property 'SomeProperty' of null`.

I have added the provider to test as well

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
      imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, RouterTestingModule, HttpModule],
      providers: [AuthService,
        SettingsService,
        AppConfig,
        {
            provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
            useFactory: initConfig,
            deps: [AppConfig],
            multi: true
        },
        ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
```

Any pointers to resolve this?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share more code? I don't see `SomeProperty`

Comment: Have you figured out the solution?

Answer (score 6):

looks like there is an issue with how Angular treats the APP_INITIALIZER while running tests (see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24218).

The workaround for now is to call this before in each: test

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    // until https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24218 is fixed
    await TestBed.inject(ApplicationInitStatus).donePromise;
  });
```

for angular <9, use TestBed.get(...) instead.

Comment: I tried it and it works great, but I wanted to know if this solution makes the test engine to wait until all APP_INITIALIZER promises are fulfilled.

It should me marked as the correct answer, imho.

Comment: Hi Ramiro, yes I believe you are correct. My understanding is that this async/await pattern makes each test execution wait until the APP_INITIALIZER promise is fulfilled. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I spun my wheels on something like this for a while. In the end I just provided a mock of the service in the "deps" of the APP_INITIALIZER provider and made sure it didn't do anything in the unit tests.

Then you just test the initializer and service independently and I think that's the best you can do.

Answer (score 0):

I think to separate test is a good idea. So, I mocked the config into my test and worked. Of course, I had to create another spec to ConfigService.

```
describe('My unit test', () => {
  
  const mock= { get myConfig() { return { url: 'http://mock' }; } };
  ...

  beforeEach(async () => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [...],
      declarations: [...],
      providers: [
        { provide: ConfigService, useValue: mock}
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
      ...
  });

...
});
```

Comment: your reference link is dead